# Heroku Container : stderr: "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, heroku

i am trying to create an API using Node.js through which any c++ program is compiled and result the is received over POST request .

```js
     const { c, cpp, node, python, java } = require("compile-run");  
      app.post("/", (req, res) => {
      //console.log(req.body);
      var compile_code = req.body.code;
      var cc = 1;
      fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/codes/run" + cc + ".cpp", compile_code);
    
      cpp.runFile(__dirname + "/codes/run" + cc + ".cpp", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(result);
          res.send(result);
        }
```

So far it is working fine on local machine , but after deploying on heroku it shows this error

> stderr: "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory\n",

i have also tried to update gcc package and otther necessary things inside Heroku container

but still i am getting this error .

Note : GCC version in heroku container

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc
```

Comment: Show how your are building your Docker container or what buildpacks you are using.

Comment: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku-community/apt.tgz

Comment: i am using this to install python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev g++ gcc these in my dyno container by using aptfile

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AADAla0dEw      logs while building is attached in this link

Comment: You are installing "`Installing g++_4%3a7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb`" you can see what kind of files it provides [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/g++_7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb.html). If we compare to a [different package](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/g++-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb.html) you can see that one does not provide `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus`. I don't know if it is possible but if it is try to provide a version in your `Aptfile`

Comment: you are right this might be the problem. but when i try to add http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/g++-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.debapt  in aptfile , still  the gcc version remains 7.5 , how can i do that . how can i opt for 7.3 instead of 7.5 which always get invoked every time , i have tried to install it through aptfile but failed to do so , is there anything else i can d0?